# ios/jquery/metatag - remove automatic website resize on ipad

Tags: ios, ipad, resize

it's possible with jquery or metatag remove the automatic resize in my website when i visit it on ipad? Is there a way to preveni this action of safari ipad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across the metatag "viewport".

I use it to strictly define the size of mobile websites and prevent scaling.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

By changing the width I expect you can force your website to a given width on all devices.

By querying the device using Javascript `navigator.useragent` you can restrict this to just iPad.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) ...
```